# Typescript global enum that gets inlined on compilation

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an enum that gets used almost everywhere in my project. I don't want to import it in each and every file. Is there a way to define an enum in the `.d.ts` file so that it gets inlined when compiled to js?

in my `types/global.d.ts` file I tried

```
declare enum MessageType {
    DIRECT = 'direct',
    FORWARDED = 'forwarded'
}
```

When I run the app I get `MessageType.DIRECT is not defined` error somewhere in my code, where I try to use it. I never imported this enum because tslint recognizes it and the autocompletion works as well.

I also tried `declare const enum ...` with the same effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  Might be related to a bug that was fixed in the latest release (TS 3.7).  See this GitHub issue for details https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33060

Answer (score 3):

By using `declare`, you've created an ambient enum, which mean you're defining the shape of an existing object, so this is just generating types, not an actual object.

If you remove `declare`, it'll create both the type for the enum, and the object

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html has more detail on ambient enums

Comment: tslint forces me to use declare. Where should I put my enum so it remains global and I don't have to import it every time? I don't need a runtime global, I want it to stay global in my code and inlined to strings on compilation

Comment: @George If you want it to be inlined every time, there's no need to emit runtime code. Just using `declare const enum` is fine -- you shouldn't get the `MessageType.DIRECT is not defined` error because this will just transpile to `"direct" /* DIRECT */`.

Answer (score 2):

The `declare` keyword indicates that the associated function, class, etc. is defined elsewhere and TSC should not emit any runtime code for the object.

I would recommend either placing this in some typescript file other than a declaration file (`.d.ts`) and removing the `declare` or include some kind of equivalent code to be used at runtime in a `.js` file.

Comment: Does typescript have any files other than `.d.ts` to declare globals?

Comment: @George You could always create a `global.ts` file if you need to have global objects that get emitted rather than just declared.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem encountered. Define the enums as constants instead. To get around it, I defined a `constants.ts` file to store my `enums` as constants to prevent modification.
e.g. In your case:

```
// constants.ts
export const DIRECT = 'direct'
export const FORWARD = 'forward'

// main.ts
import { DIRECT, FORWARD } from 'constants.ts'
// ... use DIRECT or FORWARD accordingly
```

If you are using the `enum` in your type definitions, consider avoid using `enum` and just specify the values directly e.g.

```
// types.d.ts
interface User {

    name: string
    role: 'USER' | 'ADMIN' // instead of using enum, define the values that the field can take on

}
```